# Why color filter mosaic is still fixed for each camera model?

Tags: camera, matrix, pixels

Color filter mosaic (color filter array) is fixed pieces of material that change input ray into another one and built over each pixel of camera matrix.

Why it is still fixed? Is it possible to build filter with changing colors?

Something like rotational mechanism on picture. Ray going through two lenses and if we want to change filter color we rotate figure and also change pair of active lenses. Is it possible technicaly build this prism over each pixel?[image: rotatinal mech. with three lenses]

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Expanding the capabilities of the camera.

Comment: What new capabilities would your proposal give you, though?

Comment: Using the mosaic that is necessary for the task. For example, tasks in computer vision.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could do it perfectly, you'd be trading off space-division multiplexing for time-division multiplexing, which would have serious consequences for the sensitivity (integration time) of the array. You'd also be generating three times as much data per frame. I don't see any advantage here.

The human visual system has lower resolution for color (cones) than for black-and-white (rods), and the Bayer system is designed to take advantage of that at the earliest possible point in the signal pipeline.

Comment: I propose to change mosaic for full camera matrix. Each pixel can have it's own filter. Simple idea. No reason to create 3 photos.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what the filter is doing. Each pixel can only capture one color at a time. If you want a full-color image, you need at least 3 colors for each pixel. With the Bayer pattern, the two missing colors for each pixel are interpolated from the neighboring pixels.

Comment: Your description of Bayer's device does not contradict my thinking about changing the mosaic.  I'm wondering if it's possible to build a device that controls the number of each color in each tile. And this device seems to me to be rotating lenses. Or something else

Comment: @Moorhuhn It might be possible, but it definitely is not practical, which is why hyperspectral cameras do not work like that.  There are decades of papers on this topic, those might be a better place to start than stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

The color filters have to be aligned to the pixel grid with sub-micron accuracy while physically touching it, so moving them would not be trivial or inexpensive. You also cannot rotate them since they must be aligned normal to the pixels, so you'd have to physically remove the array and then somehow align a new one.

As for putting a prism in front of each pixel, you can do that, but the spectral dispersion you get from a prim depends on how far the beam has to diverge before the detector. If the prism is touching the pixel it has zero distance and thus no effect.

Comment: `you'd have to physically remove the array and then somehow align a new one` ... that would be possible if there was a way to create a 4D object

Comment: @jsotola Maybe I'm missing the significance of the '4D object'?

Comment: if a fourth dimension object passed through our 3D universe, it would look like a shape shifter to us